# Aspect got injected but advice not called

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have gone though many SO questions to understand the configuration on Spring AOP but I couldn't find solution to my problem.  Hence briefing the configuration

Got maven multi module project with 4 modules boot, service, dao and aop.

Following BeanInitialization classe in boot maven module

```
package a.b.c;
// imports . . .
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class BeanInitialization {
    @Bean
    public MyAspect getMyAspect(){
        return new MyAspect();
    }
    @Bean MyDaoImpl getMyDaoImpl(){
        return new MyDaoImpl();
    }
    // more initializations goes here
}
```

MyDaoImpl.java as follows form service module

```
package d.e.f;
// imports . . .
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao{
    public ReturnObject create(param1, param2){
        // some logic goes here
    }
    // some other methods
}
```

MyAspect.java from aop maven module

```
package x.y.z;
@Aspect
public class MyAspect(){
    @After("execution(public * d.e.f.MyDaoImpl.create(..))")
    public void doStuffAfterMethodExecution(){
        // do some stuff here
    }
}
```

Serivce layer simply calls the dao layer.

I have gone through many formums and SO questions. As per my knowledge every configuraiton is fine.  Beside these things, advice wasn't executed on completion of create method.

Am I missing anything here?

Following are mavne dependencies I have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I included aspectj runtime dependency as well. Nothing turned out successfull.  Could someone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Added debug stack trace
[image]
Here I would like to run my advice after the create method in DAO execution completes.
Note:  I modified the class names in the above code just for simplicity.  Control flow is like, Authentication filter, REST controller, service and finally DAO

Added @Before advice in Aspect for REST controller as follows, But that wasn't executed either

```
@Before("execution(* <<package_Hierarchy>>.ResourceController.create(..)");
```

As per the stack trace it created CGLIB proxy on controller (no interface impelementation), but no Java Dynamci proxy got created on DAo object

Comment: @Bean public MyDaoImpl getMyDaoImpl() -- typo and MyDaoImpl from dao module

Comment: how did you configure your bean scan path? is x.y.z package under scan path?

Comment: @NarendranSolaiSridharan Its a boot application, we just include the BeanInitialization class to be part of context while booting up the applicaiton.  No additional scan paths defined. However aspect is getting injected.  I tested by adding some logs in dummy constructor

Comment: ComponentScan can be included to scan additional path apart from default package where the configuration is defined. you can also use "call" instead of "execution" in pointcuts.